# Linux command fatload cannot found

Tags: linux

I am just trying to boot arm from SD card according to the instruction. I met the problem fatload: command not found, but haven't found anything to be installed. How should I solve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`fatload` appears to be a subcommand of the `mmc` program, as described in this page related to Analog Devices: [U-Boot and MMC/SDIO](http://blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=bootloaders:u-boot:mmc)